# SQL statement operation priority

Tags: mysql, sql

I have question about priority operation in sql statement. For example:

```
SELECT t1.c2, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.c1) as count_c1 FROM t1 JOIN t2
WHERE t2.c2 > 1 GROUP BY t1.c2 HAVING  count_c1 > 1;
```

Which filter from this query will be applied first and which last. As I understand condition in HAVING will be last, it means that server generate full record set and after that remove all rows with count_c1 < 1 and return result to client.
Condition under WHERE will be first, it means that server don't even get rows with t2.c2 < 1, but what's about DISTINCT and GROUP BY? Result will be different if server will apply DISTINCT before GROUP BY from the opposite situation(GROUP BY first and DISTINCT second). I can't find anything in documentation about this, may be you help me.

Comment: A side note: This is invalid SQL, as the ON clause is missing. JOIN is short for INNER JOIN which Needs an ON clause. But I think MySQL let's this slip unnoticed and converts the JOIN into a CROSS JOIN silently.

Answer (score 0):

Frist, like Thorsten Kettner said, your SQL syntax is actually invalid. Secondly,

The order of operations I was able to find [(source)](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm) is as follows:

> - FROM clause (this includes JOIN's)
> - WHERE clause
> - GROUP BY clause
> - HAVING clause
> - SELECT clause
> - ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 0):

The priority operation in SQL in as:

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY

You have learn about it in MVA [here](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/querying-with-transact-sql-10530?l=zw0lVg87_2304984382)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. The DBMS is free to either join first and then apply the WHERE clause or use the WHERE clause already to restrict rows to join.
2. Aggregation. Grouping by c2, counting distinct c1 in the process. You count distinct c1 *per* c2.
3. The HAVING clause (as it is dealing with the aggregated rows). MySQL allows for an alias name here, which doesn't comply with standard SQL (as the SELECT clause is not yet executed).
4. SELECT clause: Show the results.